# Reverse the order of $ \int_{0}^{a}\int_{(a^2 - x^2)/2a}^{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}f(x, y)dydx $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Reverse the order of integration of
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{a}\int_{(a^2 - x^2)/2a}^{\sqrt{a^2 - x^2}}f(x, y)dydx  $$

The usual method to reverse the order of integration is to sketch the region of integration first. But in this case the region of integration is defined by parametric equations, therefore the region of integration depends on the value of $a$. So I don't really know how to proceed here. I even checked Thomas Calculus for some example of double integrals like this, but there isn't any.

Comment: So the limits of your region depend on $a$. Pick a value of $a$, say $a=1$ or $a=2$, and sketch. Everything will stretch uniformly as $a$ increases. **HINT**: It helps to draw things without computers.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm curious if there's any particular reason you say that about the computers. I ask because ... well, I'd trust Desmos to draw something a little more accurate/representative of the behavior of a pair functions, particularly complicated-ish ones, far more than my own sloppy chicken scratch.

Comment: Parabolas and semicircles are NOT complicated. Calculators and computers truly have dumbed down math skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration domain $D$ is the region sited in first quadrant between the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and the parabola $y=\frac{a^2-x^2}{2a}$:

$$ D=\left\{(x,y)\,\,|\,\,\frac{a^2-x^2}{2a}<y<\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,\,,\,\,0<x<a\right\}$$ If you want reverse the order, that is, variable $x$ between "functions" and variable $y$ between constants, you must split the domain in two parts $D=D_1\cup D_2$ (as in picture)

[image]

with

$$ D_2=\left\{(x,y)\,\,|\,\,\sqrt{a^2-2ay}<x<\sqrt{a^2-y^2}\,\,,\,\,0<y<a/2\right\}$$

$$ D_1=\left\{(x,y)\,\,|\,\,0<x<\sqrt{a^2-y^2}\,\,,\,\,a/2<y<a\right\}$$

and then

$$\int_0^{a/2}\int_{\sqrt{a^2-2ay}}^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}f(x,y)dx\,dy+\int_{a/2}^a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}f(x,y)dx\,dy$$

Comment: Would you mind adding your thought process to your answer? I appreciate your effort but just seeing the final answer isn't very enlightening

Comment: +1 Nice picture.

Comment: Thanks @TheoBendit. I hope it will be useful to Victor.